# Rails JSONP Parsing error on receiving end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jquery, jsonp

I have a very specific issue...

I have 2 rails apps:

- App 1 makes a request to App 2 and gets a valid JSONP response.
- App 2 has been outfitted with Rack JSONP Middleware so it returns with the
  correct wrapped callback (i.e. `JQuery1919191([{[{"find_item":{"geo_lon":-74`....etc)

For some reason App 1 throws the following error in javascript console:

`JSONP Error: parsererror Error: jQueryXXXXXX was not called`.

It works fine, however, when testing this in a non-rails context. See my fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pBDyW/16/ This code (that works in this example) is the exact same code I'm using in my rails app.

What I'm confused about is HOW am I supposed to configure App 1 (the receiving app) to handle an incoming JSONP resuqest properly. I'm convinced it must be something with Rails, as calling this from a generic page, served in Apache, works fine.

Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there are (for whatever reason) subtleties in the way the rails app (App 1) seems to process the incoming request. I modified my approach, which was to render the JSON response in my controller with:

`respond_to :json`

`def json_result`

`@blah = [stuff from database]`

`respond_with @blah`

`end`

methods (recommended with the Rack JSON Middlware approach, and restored my JSON response to:

`render :json => @find_results, :callback => params[:callback]`

The difference here is an odd one. The rails *app* JSONP call will only succeed if I execute the response like this:

`success: callbackFunction`

and NOT

`success: function(){//do stuff}`

However, the latter example works in the JS fiddle. Weird. I guess it's just some kinda formatting discrepancy in Rails 3+.

Anyway, hope this was helpful to anyone who comes across it!